# Add Buttons to Relative Layout Dynamically or Extended Linear Layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to add buttons to relative layout dynamically as per button and screen width as shown in image. Number of buttons is not fixed and width of button depends on the text which is set to the button.  [image]

I tried to achieve this using below code but that to not working fine as per my requirement.
Can anyone please help me ? Please help me through this.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.genre_layout);
                    for(int i=0; i < genreList.size(); i++){

                        Button btn = new Button(MovieDetailsActivity.this);

                        btn.setText(genreList.get(i).getGenreName());
                        btn.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5);
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80333333"));


                        LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        param.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

                        if (i != 0){

                            int prevId = genreList.get(i).getGenreId();
                            param.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, prevId);
                        }
                        btn.setLayoutParams(param);
                        btn.setId(genreList.get(i).getGenreId());

                        layout.addView(btn);

                    }
```

Comment: use flowlayout 4 android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem by using FlowLayout.
Sample code and references are available [here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)
Its simple to use. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width=display.getWidth();
    btn.setWidth(width);
```

or if you have two buttons, do

```
Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width=display.getWidth();
    btn1.setWidth(width/2);
    btn2.seTwidth(width/2);
```

**Update**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramz = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             0dp, 1.0f);
```

then                         `btn.setLayoutParams(paramz);`

Comment: what number of buttons i'll have is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest use `LinearLayout` as you asked in your question and give a `Weight`.

[LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum)

Answer (score 0):

I have the code to add buttons dynamically to linear layout. Just check out whether it helps you https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QA1tAIe601fZT2Dlp1A0qDuLD0U4IqKL3f_Crx1rtkE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding dynamic buttons in relativelayout

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawerContent);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );


for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setId(i);
     btn.setText("some_text");

    // lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, <Id>);

     layout.addView(tv2, lp); 
}
```